# Rsubmit block after waitfor

Tags: sas

I have to parallelly execute several queries in SAS, using Rsubmit. Since I can run just 3 queries at a time, I have to ensure that the 4th query runs only any 1(of the 3) is completed. Can I use a rsubmit block after the waitfor option?

Here is a sample I want to execute, asynchronously,

option autosignon=yes;
options sascmd="sas";

```
rsubmit process= task1 wait=no;
#Task1 is entered here
endrsubmit;

rsubmit process= task2 wait=no;
#Task2 is entered here
endrsubmit;

rsubmit process= task3 wait=no;
#Task3 is entered here
endrsubmit;

waitfor _any_;

rsubmit process= task4 wait=no;
#Task4 is entered here
endrsubmit;

waitfor _any_;

rsubmit process= task5 wait=no;
#Task5 is entered here
endrsubmit;
```

I am unsure whether the waitfor option will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running the code using waitfor _any_ ? It should work.